# LayoutMDI all but one child form

Tags: c#, forms, mdiparent, mdichild

I have an MDI Application and have a sort of menu that has been created using a child form so it stays within the parents window. What I would like is when I call LayoutMDI (or some variation) for all but this form to be cascaded, tiled ect but I can't seem to find a way to do it.

I have tried overriding the LayoutMDI but that is not allowed (it's not virtual) and I can't seem to slap an if statement anywhere to exclude one window.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest that you change your code to;

```
form.TopLevel=false;
form.Parent=this;

form.Show();
```

Hopefully this should resolve your problem.

Comment: That sorted it, thanks very much David.

With regards to the override, that would indeed override it but would stop me from inheriting from the original method.

Thanks again.